# Kotlin Android: How to access button in a different file?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I call a function that handles a button from MainActivity?

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        doIt()
    }
}
```

DoIt.kt:

```
fun doIt(){

    var button_0 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_0)
    button_0?.setOnClickListener(){
        button_0.setText("Jo")
    }
}
```

I get Unresolved reference: findViewById

Thanks for any help.

Comment: But why are you trying to do this? There is no guarantee that `doIt()` is called from a View/Fragment/Activity/whatever that actually has a `button_0`.

Comment: The reason why I try to do this is to shrink the size of MainActivity.kt. It becomes to large for me. I can't find a way to put a class function of MainActivity in a separate File.

Comment: Well you need to separate stuff based on functionality, not just rip out blocks of code. This isn't C#, we don't have partial classes :p

Answer (score 0):

Pass the view as a param of `doIt()`

So your code should look like:

```kotlin
fun doIt(view : Button?){
    view?.let{ btn ->
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            btn.text = "Jo"
        }
    }
}
```

And in Activity

```kotlin
doIt(findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast response. Is there also a possibility to access the view without passing it through the function?

Comment: @uii no. Your android application does not have a way to globally access any part of the UI. A class can only know about a view through having a View object passed to it.

Comment: OK. But it still does not compile with the suggested code.  I get: "Unresolved reference: setText". I already imported  "android.widget.Button" in DoIt.kt

Comment: Adding an import to a class does not give you access to the object

Comment: It works after I replaced "it.setText" with "view?.setText". Hope this has not any disadvantages.

Comment: @uii you can send the Activity instead, in that you can call `findViewById()`. Define function as `fun doIt(ctx: Context) { ctx.findViewById(...) }`

Comment: @uii, I've edited the answer a bit, instead of a null check again `view?.setText` use `btn` variable as mentioned.

Comment: @Animesh Sahu: Can you please tell me, what Activity I have to pass to the doIt function. I tried `doIt(this@MainActivity)` and more and can't find an answer. Compiling always breaks with `Unresolved reference: findViewById`.

Comment: @uii `fun doIt(ctx: Activity) { ctx.findViewById(...) }` I actually misspelled it. I was naming it ctx and put Context there... ;-)

Comment: @Animesh Sahu: It finally works. :-)  Thanks for your help.